# Role of space character in assigning multiple variables in C with scanf()

Tags: c, input, output, scanf

Here is my C code

```
   #include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
  int minx, x;

  printf("Enter two ints: ");
  scanf( "%d%d", &minx, &x);

   printf("You wrote: %d %d", minx, x);
}
```

When my input is **13** , I expected the output to be **1 3**.
Isn't that how **scanf** works, in `%d%d`, it should expect 2 digits without spaces which I gave with **13**, so expected for **minx** to be **1** and **x** to be **3**, but it didn't work. When I change the input to **1 3** from **13**, it outputs **1 3**. But scanf is in `%d%d`format, not in `%d %d`format, so why it accepts the space character here? When input is **1 3**, I expected the output to be **1**, not **1 3**. What is the role of space character here,what does it actually do?

Comment: In a `scanf` format specifier, a space character means "skip 0 or more whitespace characters".  And `%d` means "skip zero or more whitespace characters, then convert an integer".  So it turns out spaces are kinda optional in `scanf` format specifiers, because most (though *not* all) of the `%`-specifiers do their own shitespace skipping.

Comment: %d reads a whole integer number in decimal format, not one digit. %d%d expects 2 numbers separated by a space or newline (otherwise it can't know when the first number finishes). If you really want to read it digit by digit you need to read it 1 character at a time using %c and then do your own conversion.

Comment: @GemTaylor Actually, it's easier to just specifier a field width for each integer (vide infra).

Comment: True you could specify a max field width=1. Forgot about that feature.

Answer (score 1):

When you input a number using `scanf` with the `%d` format, then it reads an integer ***of any number of digits***. When you have the consecutives, `%d%d` then it will read two integers ***of any number of digits***. This is exactly what you're seeing.

If you want to read only a ***single*** digit for each integer, then you must specify `1` as the input (field) width! This will do what you want:

```
scanf("%1d%1d", &minx, &x);
```